# sql statement - would like to subtract 1 date from another and get the days hours and mins inbetween

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to subtract 1 date from another and get the days hours and mins in-between.

I know there is a DateDiff function, however it does not work with all 3 time values; days hours and mins. I would like this doable in an SQL statement. Currently I have the following.

```
SELECT id, pickupdateandtime, GETDATE() AS CurrentTime, 
(DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),pickupdateandtime)) AS Days, 
(DATEDIFF(hour,GETDATE(),pickupdateandtime)) AS Hours, 
(DATEDIFF(minute,GETDATE(),pickupdateandtime)) AS Mins FROM orders
```

And it shows up like this:

[image]

If we can stick it all in 1 column that's fine too.

Comment: If your code works, then you are using SQL Server.  I tagged appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @AndyMcLaughlin about the use of the mod operator `%` here. It's very handy for this sort of thing. However, I have a general distrust of `DATEDIFF`. That function does not count the whole number of years (say) between two dates, but the number of year boundaries between them.

So `DATEDIFF` "thinks" the difference in years between `01-Jan-2000` and `01-Jan-2001` is the same as that between `31-Dec-2000` and `01-Jan-2001`.

This is why @Michael saw a need to subtract 1 from @AndyMcLaughlin's results. Unfortunately, that doesn't always work, it will depend on the individual case.

As a rule, `DATEDIFF` works well when it's used against the smallest interval you are interested in. So if you are interested in years and simply want to separate one calendar year from another, it'll serve you well.

I think the smallest interval we are interested in here is minutes. So we can use `DATEDIFF` for that, but have to work upwards from there to hours and days:

```
select
    mf.id,
    mf.pickupdateandtime,
    mf.CurrentTime,
    --The divisions in the following lines simply
    --truncate since all the numbers are integers
    --but that works in our favour here
    (mf.MinutesFull/(60*24)) as Days, 
    (mf.MinutesFull/60) % 24 as Hours,
    mf.MinutesFull % 60 as Minutes
from
    (
    select
        id,
        pickupdateandtime,
        getdate() as CurrentTime,
        datediff(minute, getdate(), pickupdateandtime) as MinutesFull
    from @orders
    ) mf
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra info. I will try his tonight. I feel like we are close, but with your suggestion i might just get to 100%.

Comment: All Set .. Thank you Steve.

Comment: No worries. I believe you are permitted to change your accepted answer if you think a new one better meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [mod operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql) `%` to remove whole days from hours and whole hours from minutes.

So you can do something like:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    pickupdateandtime, 
    GETDATE() AS CurrentTime, 
    (DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),pickupdateandtime)) AS Days, 
    (DATEDIFF(hour,GETDATE(),pickupdateandtime) % 24) AS Hours, 
    (DATEDIFF(minute,GETDATE(),pickupdateandtime) % 60) AS Mins FROM orders
```

Comment: That looks good. Never seen this % before, looks like its a remainder of sorts. Probably I will need to subtract 1 day tho too, right? 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsaNH.png